# Finding tags inside a file in python without using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been tasked with finding all text  between  tags.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

file = open("file.txt", "r")
s = file.read()
file.close()

file.encode('utf-8')

files = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', str(file))

if files:
  for link, title in files:
    print (title)
```

My txt file contains html which is not fully html valid. However the validity of the html does not matter. I cannot change the file.

The output works until it hits a span element then it just outputs a raw string.

Comment: What parser did you use with`bs`? The default parser is not dealing well with partially-valid HTML. Try `BeautifulSoup("file.txt","html5lib")`. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea.

Comment: @DYZ I cannot use beautiful soup as the assignment says I am not allowed to use it.

Comment: Tell your teacher (s)he is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not. And your `str(file)` must really be `s`.

Comment: @DYZ That is not helpful. I know beautiful soup is best and it works with that. But the requirement for the assignment says use is not allowed.

Comment: On another side note, `file.encode('utf-8')` attempts to encode a closed file handle, not the file content (which is already in the string `s`).

Answer (score 0):

Finding "all text between tags" means you don't care about the tags. So don't.

Rather than playing regex games, just split on '<' and '>'.

```
parts = [text_tag.split('<')[0] for text_tag in text.split('>')]

print('\n'.join(parts))
```

Comment: Not gonna work: most browsers will happily display `<body><<</body>` as `<<`, and the OP says his HTML is not valid.